# Should pi, the constant, be italicized or not?

Tags: notation, pi

I know of a certian ISO standard that says "don't italicize constants" but it isn't in widespread use.  So should $\pi$ be in italics or not? What's more common in actual usage?

Feel free to tell me how to improve, this being my first question here.

Comment: Everyone uses \$\pi\$ in $\LaTeX$ to obtain $\pi$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes I am aware of that. But should pi be italicized as a general rule of thumb? Is "italicized pi" in any way different from "not italicized pi"?

Comment: Font designers have provided different ways of writing the letter "pi". They do not seem to be readily available in MathJax. If I write `\unicode[Times]{x3c0}` I get $\unicode[Times]{x3c0}$, which looks different from $\pi$ (`\pi`) in my browser--you may or may not have the same experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link that you might find helpful:

https://www.shearsoneditorial.com/2012/07/typographical-conventions-for-mathematics/

The second last paragraph says that in some style guidelines, it should be italicized, and in others it shouldn't.   So the final answer is:  It depends on who is editing your paper.

Comment: Which in this case is ... myself. I'm self publishing.

Comment: The article I cited gives two different style guidelines.  Think about your audience and then decide whose style manual to follow.

Comment: Earlier on the linked page, the second bullet item says to put $\pi$ in roman type. (I confess to having no idea what "roman" or "italic" might mean for lower-case Greek letters. I also confess to disagreeing with at least one of that page's recommendations.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass  I admit that the difference between roman and italic in Greek letters is pretty much lost on me.  Shouldn't it it be Hellenic vs Athenic or something?